# How to compare / evaluate parametric growth curves

Tags: regression, goodness-of-fit, growth-model

So I fit a set of (nested) growth models (logistic, gompertz, richards, plus some variants, eg. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalised_logistic_function ) to random sub-samples of my data to figure out which of the models is the 'correct' one.

I'm aiming at two results:

1) The model that explains my data best

2) The model that is most robust with regards to model fitting stability/measurement errors (that's why I do random subsampling)

My question is: how to best go about it? I'm not really experienced in this... I know that R2 is nonsensical for nonlinear models, so what should I do? Do pair-wise F-tests? Evaluate the deviation of each parameter in each model over the individual runs - but then how to deal with different degrees of freedom?